# Como adicionar bordas nas colunas e linhas de um TableLayout via código:

Tags: android, tablelayout

Eu criei uma tabela, porém preciso adicionar linhas e colunas na tabela via código. Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso? Agradeço desde já.

Como preciso que fique:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se ajuda? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7117665/5524514

Answer (score 1):

Não tem uma maneira direta de fazer isso, vocÊ terá que trabalhar com background, padding e margins.

abaixo uma idea do que você pode tentar trabalhar.

```
      <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#ff0000">
        <TableRow android:background="#00ff00" android:layout_margin="2dip">
            <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:text="+" android:background="#0000ff" android:layout_margin="2dip"/>
            <TextView android:text="@string/label"  android:background="#0000ff" android:layout_margin="2dip"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/amount"  android:background="#0000ff" android:layout_margin="2dip"/>

</TableRow>
```

código retirado e traduzido [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117533/how-to-give-border-of-cells-in-tablelayout-in-android/7117665#7117665)

Comment: Que coincidencia, é o mesmo link que postei nos comentarios, no mesmo instante que você publicou a resposta O.o

Comment: kkkk, verdade, quais as chances

Comment: Se formatasse o código ele ficaria mais legível. É uma forma de valorizar a sua resposta.